# Can't listen on events within the jQuery UI Autocomplete menu

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

## The problem:

I've tried listening on several different types of events within the jQuery UI autocomplete menu, for example `.on('click')` and `.on('submit')`.

None of the events are caught. In the case of the `click` event, the event isn't registered at all. And in the case of the `submit`, I try preventing default on the form `id`, but to no avail.

Essentially my use case for this is that I'm using the autocomplete to show possible options for an `input`, and appending an extra `li` to the menu on the `open` event with a button/form to add another option.

Can I simply not listen on events for some reason within autocomplete, other than the specified events like `select`?

## jsFiddle

[Here's a short jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jUsqx/1/).

Comment: When you say you're appending an extra li with a button, do you mean you're doing that dynamically?

Comment: @kinakuta I added a jsFiddle so you can see exactly what I mean.

Comment: Are you trying to listen to an event for when someone selects something from the autocomplete list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) the click event because the button element is added dynamically and isn't present when you bind it with the .on() event binder.

```
$('body').delegate('#add-from-search','click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');
});
```

[Look at this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JYr9j/1/)

[From Jquery on.() docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

Comment: Yep, this was exactly right. I was using the new `.on` syntax to replicate the now-deprecated `.live`, which was incorrect.

Comment: Actually, `delegate` is deprecated as well (check the docs). You can use `on` to accomplish what `delegate` used to accomplish: `$('body').on("click", '#add-from-search', function() {
    alert('clicked');
});`